# Initialize Array of Objects with Default Constructor without Manual Initialization of Each

Tags: c#

I have a feeling I might get downvoted for this, but I really did try to look it up.

I want to initialize an array of class type objects. errr...ref type, I think they call it in C#. I want an array of non-primitive, non struct, types.

After Googling and reading Stack Overflow Answers, the only syntax I came across is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Person
    {
        static int _nextId = 1;
        int _id;

        public Person()
        {
            _id = _nextId++;
        }
    };

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person[] people = new Person[]
            {
                new Person()
              , new Person()
            };

            if( people[0] == null)
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Your C# syntax is wrong, noob");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My problem with this, is that surely I do not want to call new Person 100,000 times, if I want an array of that size. I suppose I could do it in a for loop, but doesn't the language have something built in to simply initialize some number of objects in an array using the default constructor, without the manual initialization being required for each one?

Comment: LINQ might help a bit, like this: `var oneHundredPeople = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ => new Person()).ToArray();`

Comment: Never hide wonky code.  A for(;;) loop is "oh, he meant to do that", a one-liner is "wtf is he hiding".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generify the solution:

```
    public T[] arrayOf<T>(int count) where T : new()
    {
        T[] arr = new T[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = new T();
        }

        return arr;
    }

    private void usage()
    {
        Person[] persons = arrayOf<Person>(100);
    }
```

Comment: I like this, but it raises the question for someone, like myself, who is coming from C++, why doesn't the language do this for us?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz suppose Person class has two constructors. Then you need array of 1000 people, but you want to initialize it using non-default constructor. If array was automatically initialized using default constructor like you propose - you would have initialized 1000 useless person objects. And what if there is no parameterless constructor at all?

Comment: @Evk Well, those problems only arise if you don't have an _optional_ initialization mechanism. I suppose I am looking for a language equivalent of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill As to my understanding, it looks like C++ always init an object when we make a collection unless we have a collection of pointers. While on the otherhand, C# is going to initialize both the array and its contents to null until you do otherwise yourself. Right?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz you should try java, it doesn’t have even half c# has :)

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Both C++ and C# initialize arrays to their default value.  For reference types in C# (just like pointers in C++, as they're the same fundamental idea) that's `null`.  For value types (which is any non-pointer type in C++, and any `struct` in C#, that's the value returned from the type's parameterless constructor.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz C# array of reference types is basically array of pointers. I think it would be weird in C++ too if array of pointers (so, `Person **people`) would somehow magically initialize all elements automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate each one, but you can use a loop:

```
Person[] people = new Person[100000];

for (int i = 0; i < people.Length; i++)
    people[i] = new Person();
```

Comment: @Ilyan You shouldn't do that in this case since `Person` is a reference type. From the link you provided: "This method is designed to help compilers support value-type arrays; most users do not need this method. **It must not be used on reference-type arrays**."